# Can I show a modal pop-up instead of showing a progress indicator?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax

Can I show a modal pop-up instead of showing a progress indicator? I want to make the user wait - they shouldn't be able to do anything until the task is completed. I found possible solutions that use an update panel, but not a progress bar.

Comment: Where are you showing a progress indicator? How are you showing the progress indicator? There isn't enough detail about your specific project to answer this question. You want to block interaction with your website until a task completes, instead of updating a progress indicator? Is that it?

Comment: use progress bar with div on full screen with a opacity

Comment: @djacobson  Like i sending a mail to a User.i hit the button to send mail Untill Mail action is performed. i only want to make Wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably really want to do both: show a modal progress indicator, that doesn't allow the user to send new postback events.

[Here's](http://weblogs.asp.net/guillermo/archive/2008/02/24/ajax-how-to-create-a-quot-processing-quot-modal-window-using-updateprogress-and-modalpopup-asp-net-ajax-controls.aspx) a blog showing how to combine the modal and progress bar controls into one.

Comment: Link no longer active.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:UpdateProgress id="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">

<progresstemplate>

<div style="width:600px;height:600px;background-color:Gray;filter:alpha(opacity=70);opacity:0.7" >
<IMG id="img2" alt="" src="ajax-loader.gif" />

</div>
</progresstemplate>
```

or try [this](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/42980-How-show-progress-bar-ASP-Net.aspx) link